# undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass - referential association - rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

could one kindly advise me how to define `@friend` in my controller. i have defined `@friend` as `@friend = User.find_by_email(params[:id])` but this is not being picked up. if one could kindly explain i would be very grateful

> i currently get this error

```
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
```

[image]

views/cards/show.html.erb

```
  <div class="current_connection">
    <%= friendship_status(@user, @friend) %>
  </div>
```

in my cards_controller.rb

```
class CardsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_card, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_filter :setup_friends

  def index
    ...
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    ...
  end

  ...

  private
    def set_card
      @card = Card.find(params[:id])
    end

    def setup_friends
      @user = User.find(current_user.id)
      @friend = User.find_by_email(params[:id])
    end

    def card_params
      params.require(:card).permit(:title, :event_id)
    end
end
```

frienship_helper.rb

```
module FriendshipsHelper
  # Return an appropriate friendship status message.
  def friendship_status(user, friend)
    friendship = Friendship.find_by_user_id_and_friend_id(user.id, friend.id)
    return "#{friend.firstname} is not in your network (yet)" if friendship.nil?
    case friendship.status
    when 'requested'
      "#{friend.firstname} wants to connect with you"
    when 'pending'
      "You have requested to connect with #{friend.firstname}"
    when 'accepted'
      "#{friend.firstname} is in your network"
    end
  end
end
```

routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  devise_for :users
  resources :users do
    resources :events
  end

  resources :events do
    resources :cards
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like `params[:id]` doesn't contain user's email, it contains card's ID instead. Please check your parameters carefully.

`User.find_by_email(params[:id])` will return `nil` if any user with `email == params[:id]` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

@friend = User.find_by_email(insert email parameter here).

@friend = User.find(params[:id]) will return a User object whose id is equal to params[:id] if it exist in the database.

Here is how to use find_by : http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find_by
Here is how to use find: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/find